# The pointer will also create the row according to the sum of the counter

Tags: sql-server, view

I want to multiply the row according to the return value of a query that is in view

```
select count(col1)as COUNTS from TABEL_NAME

|   Result  |
|--------------------------------------
|   COUNTS  |
--------------------------------------
|   5       |
--------------------------------------


create view _LISTING as 

(select count(col1) as COUNTS from TABEL_NAME)... as ROWS (?) from .... (?)


select *from _LISTING

|   Result  |
|--------------------------------------
|   ROWS    |
--------------------------------------
|   Result1 |
|   Result2 |
|   Result3 |
|   Result4 |
|   Result5 |
--------------------------------------
```

how should I create such a query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
CREATE VIEW  [dbo].[vw_LISTING] 
AS
WITH Cte 
AS
(
SELECT COUNT(1)OVER() AS Cnt ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Id
FROM  [dbo].[Customer]
)
SELECT 'Result'+ CAST(Id  AS VARCHAR ) AS ReqResult 
FROM Cte

GO

SELECT COUNT(1) AS [Count]
FROM  [dbo].[Customer] --Here this customer table contains 4 record only

Result
------
[Count]
----------    
4

SELECT * FROM [dbo].[vw_LISTING] 

ReqResult
---------
Result1
Result2
Result3
Result4
```